# Разделить строку по первому числу

Tags: java

Имеется строка в формате

```
24 Example 62.34 7
```

Нужно достать из этого первое число

```
24
```

И отдельно нужно получить всё, что после первого числа.

```
 Example 62.34 7
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот решение на регулярных выражениях.

```
String s = "24 Example 62.34 7 ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s+)([0-9]+)(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

Output

```
24
 Example 62.34 7
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь у меня новая задача. Из этой же строки достать все, что идет после первой цифры.
Ввод: 24 Example 62.34 7
Вывод: Example 62.34 7
Нет разницы, каким способом будет реализовано.

Comment: @Владислав, обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Например, используя [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
String input = "24 Example 62.34 7";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
int firstInt = s.nextInt();
// firstInt == 24
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/TSB8lH

Comment: @LEQADA: Это да, но для такой задачи сканер по идее лучше :)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь у меня новая задача. Из этой же строки достать все, что идет после первой цифры.
Ввод: 24 Example 62.34 7
Вывод: Example 62.34 7
Нет разницы, каким способом будет реализовано.

Comment: @Владислав: Это уже новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно разными способами. Например регулярками. Но, если после первого числа у вас всегда идёт пробел, то можно просто строку по пробелу на массив разбить и отбросив первый элемент собрать заново:

```
String input = "24 Example 62.34 7";
String[] array = input.split(" ");
String result = "";

for(int i = 1; i<array.lenght; i++)
{
    result += array[i];
    if(i != array.lenght-1) result+=" ";
}
System.out.println(result);
//выведет: Example 62.34 7

//Первое число можно вывести соответственно так:
System.out.println(array[0]);
//выведет: 24
```